# Backtracking recursion question

Tags: recursion, backtracking

There is a bag that can take X kilogram.
You will get an array of stuff and their weight.
Print true and the each weight of the stuff
and false if there is no answer

Example:

```
for X=20
array {4,9,1,15,7,12,3}
print true and 4 1 15 (4+1+15=20)
```

Comment: What language are you interested in? Is this homework?

Comment: Also, I don't understand the question. What are you trying to do with that array?

Comment: Sounds like a simplified version of the knapsack problem.

Comment: @gbox - Looks a lot like homework.  I've tagged it as such, and will point you towards the meta guidelines about homework questions:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variation of [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

You can find some guidelines of approaching this using backtracking [here](http://www.cs.umsl.edu/~sanjiv/classes/cs5130/lectures/bt.pdf).